# How to resolve onclcik listener issue in different xml layout?

Tags: android-listview, onclicklistener

In android i design one list view with two buttons,now i want to set **onclicklistener**  on one button but in different class.so i wrote one code

```
View view1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_installation);
        Datalist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.installationList);

        ButtonLayout ViewButton=new ButtonLayout();


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hashMap");


       SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Installation.this, arl,
                R.layout.activity_button_layout, new String[]
                        {   
                        TAG_Title,TAG_URL 
                         }, new int[] { 
                        R.id.InnerText1,R.id.URL1 });


       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        Datalist.setAdapter(adapter);


        view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_button_layout,null);


        ViewButton.ClickButton = (ImageButton)view1.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
        ViewButton.ClickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "*********");
              }
            });
```

but when i am running my application then it is stopped,so can you help me

**Logcat**
[image]

Comment: Can you post your logcat ?

Comment: i posted log-cat ,now can you resolve my error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems on your XML, your button have the following attribute :

```
android:onClick="clickImage"
```

(correct me if I'm wrong, I'll edit)

You didn't declared any method named `clickImage()` in your activity, so when you click on the button, it throws an exception.

So just create a `public void clickImage(View v){}` in your activity (or fragmentà that does what you want performed on click.

Comment: i tried this one,but getting error on view.onclicklistener that is  an unimplemented method                   ViewButton.ClickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       
       
       public void clickImage(View v){}
      
      
         });

Comment: You need to implement this method in the Activity / Fragment, not inside another method.
You may remove your `setOnClickListener()` line as you already provided it in the XML.